# How to mock an HTTP method of a REST message for ServiceNow ATF tests?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, servicenow, outbound

How to mock an HTTP method of a REST message for ServiceNow ATF tests?

In case one wants to test a solution involving outbound REST integrations, like the one presented in '[Outbound REST Integrations](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/courses/utah/app_store_learnv2_rest_utah_rest_integrations/app_store_learnv2_rest_utah_outbound_rest_integrations/app_store_learnv2_rest_utah_exercise_create_an_outbound_rest_message)', it is helpful to be able to mock the involved REST service.

How to do that?

**Background**

According to the [ServiceNow API Reference / REST APIs / Automated Test Framework support](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/utah-api-reference/page/integrate/inbound-rest/concept/c_RESTAPI.html#d791565e965), the Automated Test Framework (ATF) supports inbound - but not outbound - REST test steps.

I'd expect that outbound REST test steps are supported as well, with the ability to mock responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I worked out how to mock a ServiceNow REST message HTTP method for ATF tests.

The solution (below) has a number of steps, but isn't complicated.

On the 'IPInfo' example presented in '[Outbound REST Integrations](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/courses/utah/app_store_learnv2_rest_utah_rest_integrations/app_store_learnv2_rest_utah_outbound_rest_integrations/app_store_learnv2_rest_utah_exercise_create_an_outbound_rest_message)', the solution is like this:

1. Goal: Mock HTTP method 'GetIPInfo' of REST message 'IPInfo' (which normally calls 'https://ipinfo.io/${ipaddress}/${specific_field}').
2. Create a scripted REST API, for example in scope 'x_1234567_iplookup', with API ID 'mock_ipinfo_io_api'.

   1. Create a scripted REST resource in it, to match the REST message 'IPInfo' to mock:

      Active: false

      Relative path: /{ipaddress}/{specific_field}

      Requires authentication: false

      Script:

```
(function process( /*RESTAPIRequest*/ request, /*RESTAPIResponse*/ response) {


    response.setContentType('application/json; charset=utf-8');
    response.setStatus(200);
    var writer = response.getStreamWriter();


    // Only the "city" field will be tested in this example.
    let responseJson = {
        "ip": "8.8.8.8",
        "hostname": "dns.google",
        "anycast": true,
        // This is the value that will be tested:
        "city": "Mock City",
        "region": "California",
        "country": "US",
        "loc": "37.4056,-122.0775",
        "org": "AS15169 Google LLC",
        "postal": "94043",
        "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
    };
    writer.writeString(JSON.stringify(responseJson));


})(request, response);
```

3. Create a test:

   Enable parameterised testing: true

   1. Exclusive parameter definitions:

      | Column Label | Column Name | Type | Reference | Reference Qual. Condition |
      | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
      | Expected City | u_expected_city | String (Full UTF-8) |  |  |
      | Given HTTP Method | u_http_method | Reference | HTTP Method |  |
      | Given Instance Name | u_instance_name | Reference | System Property | Name is instance_name |
      | Given IP Address | u_ip_address | String |  |  |
      | Given Mocking Path | u_given_mock_endpoint | String |  |  |
      | Given Mocking Scripted REST Resource | u_given_mocking_scripted_rest_resource | Reference | Scripted REST Resource |  |
   2. Create a test run data set:

      Given IP Address: 8.8.8.8

      Given Instance Name: instance_name

      Given Mocking Path: /api/x_1234567_iplookup/mock_ipinfo_io_api/${ipaddress}/${specific_field}

      Given HTTP Method: GetIPInfo

      Expected City: Mock City

      Given Mocking Scripted REST Resource: Get given field by IP address
   3. Create test steps:

      1. Record Update

         Notes: Activate the mocking service.

         Assert type: Record successfully updated

         Table: Scripted REST Resource [sys_ws_operation]

         Record: (Parameters➛Given Mocking Scripted REST Resource)

         Field values: Active := true
      2. Record Update

         Notes: Redirect HTTP method to mocking service.

         Assert type: Record successfully updated

         Table: HTTP Method [sys_rest_message_fn]

         Record: (Parameters➛Given HTTP Method)

         Field values: https://(Parameters➛Given Instance Name➛Value).service-now.com(Parameters➛Given Mocking Path)
      3. Open a New Form

         Table: IPAddressInfo
      4. Set Field Values

         Table: IPAddressInfo

         Field values: IP Address := (Parameters➛Given IP Address)
      5. Submit a Form
      6. Record Query

         Timeout: Seconds 15

         Assert type: There is at least one record matching the query

         Table: IPAddressInfo

         Conditions:

         1. 'Sys ID' is (Step 5: Submit a Form➛Record)
         2. 'City' is (Parameters➛Expected City)
   4. Mark mutually exclusive (!) tests:

      1. Any other tests that access the HTTP method(s) mocked.
4. Execute the test.

Should anyone wish to import and check out the solution above, [it can be cloned from my GitHub repository](https://github.com/kajanl/IPLookupApp/releases/tag/TestWithMockServer).